# Not able to run Matlab 2013a on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I must begin by saying I am new to Ubuntu. I have downloaded and installed Matlab 2013a using the java download manager. I have installed it in /home directory. However I am not able to run the software at all. I do not know what to do. Please do help. Thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is unsupported. Please upgrade to 14.04 (it has 5 years+ support)

Comment: What do you mean with "I am not able to run the software"? Do you get an error when invoking `matlab` from the command line?

Comment: Tim, I have upgraded to 14.04. @Andrea Lazzarotto: No, it says matlab: command not found. I know it is installed because I can see the installed file in my home directory but I cannot run it. Maybe I do not know how to.

Comment: Does this help? http://my-random-solutions.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-1404.html

Comment: @Tim, yes, it most definitely did help! Thanks a ton. Much appreciated.

Comment: Tim, maybe you could consider turning your comment into an answer, so that the OP can accept it. :)